# spring boot swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Пишу rest приложение на микросервисах, пытаюсь подключить swagger

pom.xml (controller):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>NC</groupId>
  <artifactId>service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>NC</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: Конфигурация swagger и структура проекта]

Запускаю приложение , открываю localhost:8080/swagger-ui

Выдаёт : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
Попробуй так.

Comment: Да. спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с похожей ситуацией, помогло :

localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html